# mySQL - Get shard(s) being queried

Tags: mysql, sql, sharding

I want to know what shard I am querying.  Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: What do you mean by "currently"? A query might need to access multiple shards.

Comment: You query the cluster, you don't query a particular node.

Comment: How are you achieving Sharding?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT @@hostname;` will give you the shard you are hitting; you could add `@@hostname` to a query to provide it at the same time as the rest of the `SELECT`.